# Open and create window in OS X

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nib

How can I open a nib file from a click event in Cocoa ? I have 2 nib files created; the mainmenu(default) and my customWindow. Now, what I want is when I click a certain button from the mainmenu nib file, it will trigger to open my customWindow. How can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can put both of your windows into the same nib, you can control-drag your button to the window you want to open, select "makeKeyAndOrderFront", and then uncheck "Release When Closed" and "Visible At Launch" checkboxes in the Attributes inspector.

[image: connect an action]

[image: set the attributes]

But seriously, read View Programming Guide. It will make life much easier.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code, if you are using window controller:

```
NSWindowController* yourWindowController = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"YourXIBName"];
[yourWindowController showWindow:self]
```

A generic way to do this is by using below code:

[loadNibNamed:owner:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSBundle_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSBundle/loadNibNamed%3aowner%3a)

Comment: You should call `[yourWindowController showWindow:self]` instead, that's what it's for.

Comment: its not working. window just gives blink (open and close in a second) @RobKeniger Miraaj

Comment: You need to retain the window controller, it's being released. You need to store a reference to the controller as a property or ivar.

Comment: Embarrassing that I am asking this but... Where can I find my XIBName?

Answer (score 2):

Nibs are just visual representation of a view graph with connections to objects in your code. Start with the basics, read [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503).

Comment: Perhaps this answer should link to the OS X section instead of the iOS guide.

Answer (score 2):

You could also link the clicking of the menu button to an IBAction in your app-delegate, which calls

```
[NSBundle loadNibNamed:"myNib" withDelegate:self];
```

I'm not sure if that's right, but check the docs for NSBundle.